# Examples on weak law of large number

Tags: probability, statistics, logic

> 30% of pickup trucks in a city are black and the weight of black pickup trucks averages 7500 pounds. Naturally, there are far fewer vehicles on an on-ramp than there are on the highway. For each of the situations below state whether A or B is more likely; or do they have the same probability (choice C)?
>
> iii) A) seeing 28 to 32% of the pickups on an on-ramp to I-99 being black B) seeing 28% to 32% of the pickups on I-99 being black
>
> iv) We see 5 pickups in a row on the on-ramp that are black on I-99. A) the next pickup on the on-ramp to I-99 is black B) the next pickup on I-99 is black

My logic:

iii) I selected A for this one because 30% of the black truck was in the city, so therefore I assume that 30% of them are coming from the track to I-99.

iv) I selected B because there are more vehicles on  I-99 than on the ramp, so I assume that are more black truck on I-99, hence it has a larger sample size compare to a smaller sample size on the ramp. Therefore, we will have a larger chance for the next given truck on I-99 to be black.

These are the two exercise problem given at a probability class. So can anyone confirm that my logic is correct? Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.